# C# execute java in command prompt with input file

Tags: java, c#, command-line, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I am writing a test program in C# that calls java program in command prompt with a input file.

The java program will call `Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);` to read screen inputs

Running in command prompt without C# is ok

```
>java jvProgram  < case1.in
```

the program execute without asking the inputs, which is excepted.

Now I am try to use C#:

```
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"java ";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments += " jvProgram < case1.in";
            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
```

The java program will actually wait for my input to execute, that means the `< case1.in` does not work.

The result is like running command prompt

`>java jvProgram`   without `< case1.in`

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this would make a difference but should the file name really be "java " (with a space)?

Comment: the same with/without space

Comment: "<" is cmd (shell) specific command. You are running process with `UseShellExecute = false`, so this command is not processed. Instead - write contents of your file to standard input of the process yourself (so, what "<" does for you in a shell).